# Not able to click on element of table in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I want to click on an element in a table the html code of element is following

```
<A onclick="return A_MENUS[0].onclick(4);" onmouseover=A_MENUS[0].onmouseover(4); onmousedown=A_MENUS[0].onmousedown(4); onmouseout=A_MENUS[0].onmouseout(4); id=e0_4o class=m0l1oout style="HEIGHT: 20px; WIDTH: 250px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 600px; Z-INDEX: 4; TOP: 98px; VISIBILITY: hidden" href="WebMenu.aspx"><DIV id=e0_4i class=m0l1iout>Start Proposal</DIV></A>
```

Following is screen short,after clicking on underwriting I am not able to click on motor. The code is working on a pc but not working on another one. Please help me.
Code is bellow

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(wDriver, 150);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("home")));
wDriver.findElement(By.id("home")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("e0_5991o")));
wDriver.findElement(By.id("e0_5991o")).click();
customSleep(1000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("e0_6101o")));
wDriver.findElement(By.id("e0_6101o")).click();
customSleep(1000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("e0_6128o")));
wDriver.findElement(By.id("e0_6128o")).click();
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried maximizing the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

first try this :

```
 (JavascriptExecutor(webdriver)).executeScript("document.getElementById('ur id').click();");
```

if this does not work, than try this:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("ur xpath"));//u may use by id or by class as ur wish
String makeVisible = "arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(makeVisible, elem);
```

and than click on ur element like this

```
elem.click();
```

if the element is not visible in screen, than first scroll to that element like below:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("ur xpath"));

 //this line will scroll down to make element visible
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + elem.getLocation().x + "," +(elem.getLocation().y- 100) + ");");
```

after element visible in ur screen, than click by normal driver click or javascript click.

Comment: Thanks but it is not working giving following error
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: JavaScript error
Code is 
JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor)wDriver;
jsExec.executeScript("document.getElementById('e0_5991o')[0].click();");

Comment: sorry, i made this typing mistake...i updated the code

Comment: u can also try with the other alternative solution.

Comment: Sorry but not working the error was gone but  
'jsExec.executeScript("document.getElementById('e0_5991o').click();");'  is not clicking on element . Please help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110614/discussion-between-noor-and-shik).

Comment: if ur element is not shown in screen, i mean if u need to scroll down, than use my last solution. but if no need to scroll down than use my secod solution , i hope that will work fine.

Comment: I am working on IE 11 and if I am right in IE you have to make xpath and I am new in selenium so don't have idea, how to make xpath. Do you have anything like firebug for IE

Comment: u can use xpath or id or class as ur wish.... actually in which u are comfortable. In my answer i write by xpath, but there u can use by id or by class or others.

Comment: I have already tried with id, but not working all three options. I want to try by xpath. I had gon throw the link - http://www.testingdiaries.com/find-xpath-in-ie-browser/ . But this way is also not working.